# When setting up GKE internal load balancers why can I access the IP address from a separate VM but not within the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

I have a K8s deployment running in GKE which is connected to an internal load balancer service which assigns an IP address to the VPC subnetwork. When I spin up an individual Compute VM in the subnetwork I am able to access the deployment using the ILB IP address, but I cannot access the deployment within the cluster or from another GKE cluster hitting the same IP address.

I am not sure what I am missing, or if an ILB is not the right tool for this use case. The end goal is to communicate between different GKE clusters on the same subnetwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access from a VM but not from the cluster is strange. The cluster, VM, ILB must be in the same region and subnet.

Also here [1] you could find an example about how to create an internal load balancer for GKE. You can check the example config and your ILB config.

I test this with a curl to ILB and works from a VM instance, from inside the cluster or from a different cluster in the same zone.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing

Comment: Thank you for the link, it lead me to my issue. My load balancer had ```loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 10.129.0.0/24``` which was preventing K8s cluster pods from connecting correctly. Taking this out created the expected result